# Toggle enable/disable between 2 textfields which accept only numbers in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I have 2 textfields, Tx1 & Tx2 accepting numbers only.

**My requirement**

- The first time both Tx1 & Tx2 should be enabled="true".
- When inserting the first number in Tx1, Tx2 should be enable="false".
- If I delete the number, Tx1 & Tx2 should be enable="true" then if I insert the number in Tx2 , Tx1 should be enable="false".

**Possible solution**

I think I need to capture the numeric keys from the keyboard & then use focusIn(event) and FocusOut(event) (perhaps). I don't have any idea on how to capture only numeric keys

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: Thnx @DerGolem much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

There are [FocusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html) and [KeyBoardEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html) for your case.

```
Tx1.restrict = "0-9";
```

limits the input characters

Example for events:

```
import flash.events.FocusEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

Tx1.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, Tx1FocusOutListener);
Tx1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, Tx1KeyUpListener);
function Tx1KeyUpListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (TextField(e.currentTarget).text == "1") Tx2.selectable = Tx2.visible = false;
    else Tx2.selectable = Tx2.visible = true;
}
function Tx1FocusOutListener(e:FocusEvent):void {
    if (TextField(e.currentTarget).text == "1") Tx2.selectable = Tx2.visible = false;
    else Tx2.selectable = Tx2.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Can u clarify a bit more...i mean which focusEvent & on deleteing the Tx1 value Tx2 shld be enable="true"

Comment: i add example in main comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event.

```
<s:TextInput id="tx1" restrict="0-9" change="tx1Changed()"/>
<s:TextInput id="tx2" restrict="0-9" change="tx2Changed()" y="50"/>
```

---

And check how many digits typed in both TextInput.

```
private function tx1Changed():void
{
    if (tx1.text.length > 0)
        tx2.enabled = false;
    else
        tx2.enabled = true;
}

private function tx2Changed():void
{
    if (tx2.text.length > 0)
        tx1.enabled = false;
    else
        tx1.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thnx @subdan this was lot easier..!